# OpenCV with Android Studio Problems

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio

I know this has been discussed before, but I have had frustrating 3 days and I still can't get it to work. I am  following [this](https://blog.hig.no/gtl/2015/10/01/android-studio-opencv/)

After I finish 'Adding OpenCV to your new project', I get the error:

'Gradle 'opencvtest' project refresh failed' with a blank after Error

I tried everything, but even the simplest things don't work anymore. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this repository: https://github.com/gowithfloat/android-opencv-template just download and should work.

Comment: This doesn't have JNI support though.

Comment: this one is working with NDK JNI support https://github.com/leadrien/opencv_native_androidstudio